# Chamando Método do Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, button

Estou fazendo um projeto para a Faculdade, e estou tendo a dificuldade de entender como faço para criar um botão e chamar uma ActionResult no Controller, e queria saber se a action precisa estar no controller correspondente do respectivo Model.

Pra entender melhor, seria assim, uma view com 2 botões, 2 actions no controler e fazer um botão chamar a action1 e o outro chamar a action2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Estou fazendo um projeto para a Faculdade, e estou tendo a dificuldade de entender como faço para criar um botão e chamar uma ActionResult no Controller...

Se estamos falando de um `<input>` do tipo `submit` (que é um tipo de *button*), a forma correta é criando um `<form>` para ele. No ASP.NET MVC usando Razor, funciona da seguinte forma:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MinhaAction", "MeuController", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Ir para Action" 
         name="botao1" id="botao1" />
}
```

Ou usando a tag `<button>`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MinhaAction", "MeuController", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <button type="submit" name="botao1" id="botao1">Ir para Action</button>
}
```

Para funcionar, seu *Controller* precisa ter:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MinhAction()
{
    ...
}
```

> ..., e queria saber se a action precisa estar no controller correspondente do respectivo Model.

Não necessariamente. Um *Model* não é necessariamente ligado a um *Controller*. Um *Controller* pode trabalhar com 0, 1 ou N *Models*.

> Pra entender melhor, seria assim, uma view com 2 botões, 2 actions no controler e fazer um botão chamar a action1 e o outro chamar a action2

Pode ser feito assim:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MinhaAction1", "MeuController", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <button type="submit" name="botao1" id="botao1">Ir para Action 1</button>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("MinhaAction2", "MeuController", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <button type="submit" name="botao2" id="botao2">Ir para Action 2</button>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MinhAction1()
{
    ...
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MinhAction2()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: No caso de '@using (Html.BeginForm("MinhaAction", "MeuController", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Ir para Action" 
         name="botao1" id="botao1" />
}' como eu passaria meu objeto para a action? No caso meu projeto ele precisa ter um botão comprar para cada ítem, e o botão é exibido pelo foreach e cada ítem tem o ID...

Comment: Sugiro você fazer uma nova pergunta, agora falando dessa nova necessidade. É uma nova resposta, complementar a esta.

Answer (score 2):

Em ASP.NET MVC a chama da controller e através de rotas no caso quando você cria um projeto em ASP.NET MVC  você já vem com uma rota criada Home/Index o que significa isso você ira chamar HomeController e método Index que assim ele vai te direcionar para sua view na pasta Home/Index.cshtml que no caso e página desejada  para que ele consiga se direcionar para esta página no caso de você queira criar por exemplo outro action Home/sobre você teria que ter view na pasta home/sobre.cshtml vou mostrar com códigos.

Abaixo como fica no código e como foi gerado no html. 
tem essas três maneiras que você pode criar links
para redirecionamento das suas páginas você
pode usar button mas sempre vai seguir mesma regra.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seria melhor para a sua resposta não usar imagens do código, e sim código que possa ser copiado e colado. Outra coisa são exemplos de Actions de Controller.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.1

```
  <form method="post" action="/Demo/RegisterInput">
   Email:
   <input type="email" data-val="true"
          data-val-email="The Email Address field is not a valid email address."
          data-val-required="The Email Address field is required."
          id="Email" name="Email" value="" /> <br>
   Password:
   <input type="password" data-val="true"
          data-val-required="The Password field is required."
          id="Password" name="Password" /><br>
   <button type="submit">Register</button>
 <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="<removed for brevity>" />
```